# Are "Prototypal Inheritance" and "Prototype Chain" one and the same in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am learning JS now, as I am new so was looking for `inheritance in JS`. I came accross 2 words:

1. Prototypal Inheritance
2. Prototype Chain

Can you please tell me if both are same or different?
Please, I am new and am very confused. Pl help. thanks in advance.

Comment: No, "Prototypal inheritance" is the concept, "Prototype chain" is a part of the implementation of that concept.

Comment: @Teemu - Can you pls explain and add as an answer. It will help.

Comment: I think this is a basic language feature, it's very wide to explain, and you'd better to read some tutorial(s) to understand Prototypal inheritance. See for example [a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) at MDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for all intents and purposes they are referring to the same concept for someone learning JS. Are they two distinct concepts requiring separate studying of both? No. They're just two terms that relate to the same concept of inheritance in JS.

A loose analogy which I know is not perfect, but should help make sense of the two terms and how they relate:

- I have a father from whom I inherited my genetics. My father inherited his genetics from his father, and so on. This is **my prototype chain**.
- You also have a father from whom you inherited your genetics. Your father inherited his genetics from his father, and so on. That is **your prototype chain**.
- We are both using **prototypal inheritance** but we have different **prototype chains**.

---

Some developers like to argue semantics and get all technical just to flex on others, but if you are a beginner learning JS you absolutely do not need to stress that these two terms are referring to different areas of study because they are not.

Comment: @Gary ... 1/3 The chosen analogy has quite a potential to mislead. Especially with using the term *genetics* it actually matches *inheritance* in a way like most people and *`class`ic trained programmers* conceptually understand it. The conclusion with this example in my opinion rather was ... *“We both use __multiple inheritance__ (there is also a maternal inheritance line in addition to the paternal one), but each of us is a distinct (sub)class from distinct parent classes (ancestors)“.*

Comment: @Gary ... 2/3 A better analogy was ... a) I'm not able to drill a hole into my wall, because I do not own a drilling machine; but I know a friend [... of a friend [... ]], who actually owns one. I do borrow her/his machine in order to drill a hole into *(/within the context of)* my wall. ... b) You are also not able to drill a hole into your wall, because you too do not own a drilling machine; you are not my friend and therefore I do not want you to benefit from my friend's *“toolchain“*. ...

Comment: @Gary ... 3/3 ... But luckily you yourself know a friend [... of a friend [... ]] who actually owns a drilling machine. You are going to borrow her/his machine in order to drill a whole into *(/within the context of)* your wall. ... c) We both make use of a *“toolchain“*. They are distinct because the owners of each drilling device are not identical. Each one has even an own implementation of her/his tool. My (... (friend's) friend's) friend's one might be a *Bosch*. The one of your's borrowing chain might be a *B&D*.

Comment: @Gary ... ***Summary:*** The example's *“toolchain“* is like the *prototype chain*. Thus, both are implementations of the concept of *prototype based delegation*. The latter is referred to as *prototypal inheritance* because the delegation part is a built-in automated process.